# Job role changed

Tags: professionalism, job-change, team-role

I’ve been in my current position about 7 years, mainly as an IT resource on a small team. I enjoyed the work and challenge. Main duties were support, light coding, SQL, reporting.

Over the past year as a big project got underway my responsibilities have gradually changed to more of a business analyst, where I’m completing documentation and running meetings. I did not really have a choice in the change, more of management needing a body.

I like where I work, but am not excited by the role change, and the project is likely to continue for another 1.5 years.

If my current role were advertised in a posting, I would not apply for it. I also don’t expect the role to revert back to technical when the project is over.

1) What is the best way to convey my concerns to my manager?

2) Is it “bad” to look for other employment in the middle of the project?

Comment: It's never bad to look for other employment if you're unhappy with your role.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the best way to convey my concerns to my manager?

I think that having a one-on-one meeting would be the right way. There you can explain him your concerns, just like you have done here with your post. Explain him that you are happy in the company, but are not quite sure if you are enjoying your current tasks, and that you feel you can perform better with the tasks you used to do.

> Is it “bad” to look for other employment in the middle of the project?

No, I would even say that it is never bad to look for other jobs while you currently have one. Otherwise if you waited to finish all your projects before seeking a new job you will never be able to do so (usually projects just keep coming).

Just be careful and don't let your job-seeking process affect your performance at your current work. If, after talking with your manager, you don't get what you want you will probably be better seeking for job in other companies, where you actually do the tasks you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the best way to convey my concerns to my manager?
>
> Is it “bad” to look for other employment in the middle of the project?

In many small companies/teams, roles evolve to meet the needs of the company and/or team. Unfortunately, that sometimes means that the new role no longer meets your personal needs.

You should sit down with your manager and talk about your role, what you like, what you don't like, where you see it going. Don't be argumentative, but let your manager indicate the department needs.

If you conclude that what will be required of you no longer meets your personal needs, you may have to find a new job elsewhere, accept it, then give your notice and leave.

People leave in the middle of projects all the time. It's nothing to be concerned about. Likely, the question wouldn't even come up in an interview.

Comment: "Don't be argumentative" - especially as how your manager might think they're doing you a favour - they might be "guiding" your career, and could well be surprised that you don't want to do project management - after all, they're a manager and they think it's great being a manager.